# Bind master slave replication

Tags: linux, bind

It has been a long time for me since I played with Bind, I currently have Master / Slave DNS setup with, and I see that every time I update serial number on master, it gets reflected on the slave. However when I add an "A" record on master it doesn't show up on the slave.

is this a normal behavior? or it should have been automatically taken care of upon bind service restart on master?

Thank you

Comment: Do you update the serial number when you add the "A" record? The replication is triggered by a change in serial number, not by changes in other records...

Answer (score 0):

Well, after 2 hours from making the change on the master it has been replicated to the slave, I wonder why it took a long time.

Comment: I guess you are interested in the SOA (Start of Authority). This record specifies among other things the time to live of records and the time that slaves should wait to transfer information from the master.